# Ruby Net::HTTP::Post overrides custom Content-Type header

Tags: ruby, rest, http, post

It seems that Ruby's `Net::HTTP::Post` overrides the custom Content-Type header. When I set the header `'Content-Type':'application/json'` I receive the following error from the server:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Bad Content-Type header value: 'application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Notice `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. **Why is it there? Is there a way to remove it?**

My code:

```
def post(uri, params)
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type':'application/json')
  req.form_data = params
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
    http.request(req)
  }
end
```

Interestingly the following code which takes a different approach using `Net::HTTP` works:

```
def post(uri, params)
  headers = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'}
  request = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request.post(uri.path, params.to_json, headers)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in the first snippet you explicitly set `request.form_data`:

```
req.form_data = params
```

Forms are [encoded with `x-www-urlencoded` implicitly](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c08f7b80889b531865e74bc5f573df8fa27f2088/lib/net/http/header.rb#L410).

Probably you’d better to set `body` or set in explicitly in [`Net::HTTP::Post.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html#method-c-new).